# Supergravity in our universe of accelerated expansion

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-constant, supergravity, de-sitter-spacetime

In "On *supergravity theories, after ~40 years*" (Jean-Pierre Derendinger) presented on DISCRETE 2014" it is said (p.16) that a positive cosmological constant is not compatible with supersymmetry/supergravity.

In our universe the actual measured cosmological constant as parametrisation of the dark energy is very well positive.

Why supergravity is still considered as a viable model -- as effective low-energy theory of string theory and also was used a basis of the supersymmetrical model mSUGRA ? Interestingly supersymmetrical extensions of the standard model based on mSUGRA could not be confirmed up to now.

I know of the merits of supergravity in AdS spaces, but my question is about (asymptotic) de Sitter space as is our universe. So is the simplest model of supergravity (the one described in chapter 9+10 (4D or 11D) of Freedman & van Proeyen book) still compatible with the cosmological findings in our universe ? If not, is there an alternative model of Supergravity that is compatible with an accelerated expansion of the universe, i.e. an universe with a positive cosmological constant ?